# (SQL) Query Results on one row

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2014-express

So I have two tables, named "Questions" and Answers
[image: Diagramm]

I made a INNER JOIN for those two tables

```
SELECT Questions.ID, Questions.QText, Answers.AText
FROM Questions INNER JOIN Answers
ON Questions.ID=Answers.QuestionID;
```

And the result looks like this:
[image: Result]
However, you can clearly see, that the question is displayed 4 times each time with on of the answers.

Now My question is: Is it possible to have the result in one row, consisting of

[ID] - [Question] - [Answer1] - [Answer2] - [Answer3] - [Answer4]

Comment: Why do you need to have them on 1 row? I have a hard time believing doing that will solve any problems, lest cause some.

Comment: And How :)? I looked at it but I don't know how to use it. @AbdulRasheed

Comment: The problem with putting it on one row is that it makes the data much harder to process, because now the number of columns is dynamic. What if you have 1 question with 2 answers and another with 10 answers? Then the one with 2 answers will also have 8 'null' answers.

Comment: @wvdz I need this Query in C#, to get the Question with all it's answers on one row. Afterwards I process it to use it as a API

Comment: @wvdz No worries, every question has exactly 4 answers

Comment: For that usecase you really don't want to take this approach. Easiest way would be to do 1 query to get all the questions, put them in a map by id, then use a second query to load all the answers, and match them with the correct question by question id. Actually, if you order both queries by id you don't need a map, you can do it with a list.

Comment: @wvdz The problem is that I can't to really complex things, because I am an apprentice and it's the first time I work with SQL. In addition my C# experience is reduced to the basics :)

Comment: Well, I get that point. But trying to solve everything in SQL will usually lead to a codebase that will get very hard to maintain. Perhaps this might be a good opportunity to boost that C# experience?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this Query for a Pivot:

```
SELECT QID, QText, [1], [2], [3], [4]
FROM (SELECT Q.ID AS QID, A.ID AS AID, Q.QText, A.AText FROM Questions AS Q 
INNER JOIN Answers AS A ON Q.ID = A.QuestionID) QA
PIVOT
(
    MAX(AText)
    FOR AID
    IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])
) AS PV
```

BUT: You must use a combined Primary Key for your Answer Table.
With this Pivot Table the answer ID must be 1, 2, 3, 4 every time. Otherwise you don't get your answers.
`FOR AID` declares, which column is used for this.
Otherwise you could add a column to answers which called "AnswerNr" or something like that. In this column you put 1 to 4 for your answers and change the query to:

```
SELECT QID, QText, [1], [2], [3], [4]
FROM (SELECT Q.ID AS QID, ->A.AnswerNr<-, Q.QText, A.AText FROM Questions AS Q 
INNER JOIN Answers AS A ON Q.ID = A.QuestionID) QA
PIVOT
(
    MAX(AText)
    FOR ->AnswerNr<-
    IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])
) AS PV
```

Comment: But I thought it is not possible to have duplicate Primary keys?

Comment: That's true. That's the reason why you need a combined primary key. Your need to make the Columns  `ID` and `QuestionID`to your primary key. On this way the combination ID + QuestionID must be unique.

Comment: Ah Okay. I'll try it and give you a Feedback

Comment: Ok, after a long time of try and error I got it! I added a ner row called ID2 which does what you described. It works: http://imgur.com/RJBHwvt

Comment: Glad to hear that this helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

Use CROSS APPLY for CSV. Don't do it inline, then you need a grouping...

```
SELECT q.ID, q.QText, Answers = STUFF(x.csv, 1, 1, '')
FROM Questions q
CROSS APPLY
    (
    SELECT
        '-' + a.Atext
    FROM
        Answers a
    WHERE
        a.QuestionID = q.ID
    FOR XML PATH ('')
    ) x (csv)
```

Comment: The first FROM is underlined red :) "Incorrect syntax near the keyword FROM"

Answer (score 0):

To get the Question with all it's answers on single row Use `COALESCE`:

```sql
DECLARE @Answer VARCHAR(8000) 
SELECT Questions.ID, Questions.QText, @Answer = COALESCE(@Answer + ', ', '') + AText
FROM Questions INNER JOIN Answers ON Questions.ID=Answers.QuestionID
WHERE AText IS NOT NULL
```

If you're using SQL Server 2005, you could use the FOR XML PATH command.

```
SELECT Questions.ID, Questions.QText,
       (STUFF((SELECT CAST(', ' + [AText] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
               FROM Answers 
               WHERE Questions.ID = Answers.QuestionID
         FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 2, '')) AS Answers
 FROM Questions
```

Comment: I don't think this works. There needs to be a grouping at least.

Comment: @wvdz Using `COALESCE`, you don't want to group and all

Comment: What is even the point of using coalesce? The first value can never be null, right?

Comment: @VigneshKumar The Error is in German. It is Error 141. If you still want to look at it, here you go:http://imgur.com/Tc28kU0

Comment: You could've googled that error yourself and just posted the english translation for us. `A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations`

Comment: Don't do inline XML path because then you need a DISTINCT